# MEL null safe Xpath works in Studio but not Cloudhub

Tags: mule, mvel, cloudhub

The following expression works fine locally in Studio, but when deployed to Cloudhub it fails with the below error:

Its basically just a simple path expression that uses the null safe ? operator before invoke the .text method. Why doesn't this work in Cloudhub?

```
    <set-variable variableName="country"
        value="#[xpath('//ns1:root/ns1:Country').?text]"
        doc:name="Set Country" />
```

---

Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath('//ns1:root/ns1:Country').?text" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: DefaultDocument

### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer:363 (null)
2. [Error: null pointer:

Answer (score 0):

Older post but I hope the solution is useful.

Use it this way man:

`<set-variable variableName="country" value="#[?xpath('//ns1:root/ns1:Country').text]" doc:name="Set Country" />`